# Match the request URL to the correct URL pattern in web.xml

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets, web.xml

I am trying to learn how to map a request URL to a url pattern in deployment descriptor. I got all the answers right, but I am not sure if the thought process is correct. 
Please help me to confirm or make changes in the reasoning.

```
<servlet>  
        <servlet-name>One</servlet-name>  
        <servlet-class>foo.DeployTestOne</servlet-class>  
    </servlet>  
    <servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-name>One</servlet-name>  
        <url-pattern> *.do </url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet>  
        <servlet-name>Two</servlet-name>  
        <servlet-class>foo.DeployTestTwo</servlet-class>  
    </servlet>  
    <servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-name>Two</servlet-name>  
        <url-pattern> /fooStuff/bar </url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping>  
    <servlet>  
        <servlet-name>Three</servlet-name>  
        <servlet-class>foo.DeployTestThree</servlet-class>  
    </servlet>  
    <servlet-mapping>  
        <servlet-name>Three</servlet-name>  
        <url-pattern> /fooStuff/* </url-pattern>  
    </servlet-mapping>
```

1) `http://localhost:8080/MapTest/blue.do` 
Container choice: DeployTestOne (matched the *.do extension pattern)

Exact match check: Is there a URL pattern in DD which is exactly = /MapTest/blue.do ? NO. 
Directory match check: Is there any URL pattern in DD for directory /MapTest ? NO. 
Extension match: Is there a pattern in DD for files with extension .do ? Yes ! 
Select DeployTestOne !

**Question -** When doing an Exact match check, does the container look for blue.do in DD or does it look for /MapTest/blue.do ?

2) `http://localhost:8080/MapTest/fooStuff/bar/blue.do` 
Container choice: DeployTestThree (matched the /fooStuff/* directory pattern)

Exact match check: Is there a URL pattern in DD which is exactly = /MapTest/fooStuff/bar/blue.do ? NO. 
Directory match check: Is there any URL pattern in DD for directory /MapTest/fooStuff/bar ? Yes ! 
Go for the url pattern for longest pat, that is, /fooStuff/*

**Question -** When doing the directory match check, does the Container look for /MapTest/fooStuff/bar/ or just /fooStuff/bar ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the url pattern specification :

1 - A string beginning with a ‘/’ character and ending with a ‘/*’ suffix is used for path mapping.

2 - A string beginning with a ‘*.’ prefix is used as an extension mapping.

3 - A string containing only the ’/’ character indicates the "default" servlet of the application. In this case the servlet path is the request URI minus the context path and the path info is null.

4 - All other strings are used for exact matches only.

reference : [Java Servlet Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/)

Comment: Further in that document it explains in what order they are checked.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - Can you please tell me the answers to my two questions. I am not sure what is the url pattern being searched in case multiple matching directories are found.

Comment: jproton - please see my comment. I want to be sure I know the url that the container checks for. thank you.

Comment: @sidsmith As I said, the document linked in this answers explains each pattern and in what order it is checked. It's all in the specification.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - thanks. But, I only need one small thing. Do I need to scan the spec for that ? I am sure I won't need to delve deep into the spec for a long time.

Comment: @sid You don't have to read the whole thing. See chapter 12. It's in the first section.